# Tool for linux file system cache inspection

Tags: linux, filesystems, cache

I'm looking for a tool to show what portion of a file is in the file system cache. In the past I have used the fincore tool that is part of the linux-ftools package. linux-ftools isn't in any of the distributions that I use and hasn't been updated since 2012.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[vmtouch](http://hoytech.com/vmtouch/)** for this...

To see how much of SYSERR.TXT is in the file system cache,

```
[root@GreenLeaf /ppro/data]# vmtouch -v SYSERR.TXT
SYSERR.TXT
[OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO] 1859/1859

           Files: 1
     Directories: 0
  Resident Pages: 1859/1859  7M/7M  100%
         Elapsed: 0.000316 seconds
```

100% of it is!